# Wordpress uploading image : An error occured in the upload. Please try again later

Tags: wordpress

[test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqjq7.png)[test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rWpF.png)How to fix these error when Im trying to upload an image.

" ERROR NO TURBO SIDEBAR FOUND WITH ID wop-1

An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later "

Comment: Theres an image I upload. just see it

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error while uploading image or any media to WordPress you can only suspect some things and start investigation by changing and checking settings one by one
Good news – WordPress returns exact error message!

**Getting error details**

Error details are in the HTTP response from **async_upload.php** script formatted as JSON.
You can easily find it using build in **Developer Tools** in Firefox or **Developers Console** in Chrome.

**Step 1**

In Chrome or Firefox press F12 and go to Network tab.

**Step 2**

Try to upload image again or do any other action that will trigger the error.

**Step 3**

```
1. At the bottom left find async_upload.php file name.
2. Click it and go to Preview tab (see attached images).
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a very general question, and there is likely already a answer for this somewhere; but in my experience the error shows most often because (assuming it is in the correct format) the image you are trying to upload may be too big, in which case you can minimize using free online image tools.

I found [this one](http://www.reduceimages.com/) to be most effective as it handles bigger image sizes.

So minimize the image and then try to upload the new minimized image.

Comment: I already use a minimal image for about 33.8kb but still wont upload.